# Showing if two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic, we can extend this homeomorphism to the whole space.

Tags: general-topology

The motivation for this question comes from my own attempt to prove the Jordan Curve Theorem. I have the proof worked out except for the portion below. An outline of the argument is as follows:

1) Show that the regular definition of a Jordan Curve:

$\Gamma$ is the image of a continuous <s>surjection</s> injection, $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Implies if we consider $f$ as a function $f: S^1 \rightarrow \Gamma$ instead, then f is a homeomorphism.

This follows from the fact that for $g$ a continuous bijection $g: X\rightarrow Y$ such that $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $g$ is a homeomorphism.

2) From the homeomorphism $f$ we can build another homeomorphism $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ between the two spaces such that $g(x)=f(x)$ where f was defined

3) Now we can conclude $g(S^1)$,  $\;g(B_{1}(0,0))\;$ where $B_{1}(0,0)$ is the open ball radius one centered at $(0,0)$ and $g(\mathbb{R}^2-(B_{1}(0,0) \cup S^1))$ are pairwise disjoint, proving the Jordan Curve Theorem.

I am stuck on the second part of the proof. Its full statement is below.

Let $S^{1}$ be the unit circle with the subspace topology generated from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Let $f$ be a homeomorphism $f: S^{1} \rightarrow \Gamma$  such that $\Gamma$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2_{std}$

Note that $\Gamma$ is a Jordan Curve.

Show there exists a bijection (or maybe even a homeomorphism)

$g: \mathbb{R}_{std}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{std}^{2}$

Such that  $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in S^1$

Edit: $\mathbb{R}_{std}$ refers to $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.
Edit: I meant Injection! Not surjection

Comment: Your "question" reads like a challenge rather than a request for assistance. Please provide some background and tell us what work you have done on the problem.

Comment: Fair enough, hold on.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^2_{std}$? Simply $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: In response to the title (but not the body) of the question: the homeomorphism $1/n \mapsto n$ between the discrete subspaces $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, \ldots\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ doesn't extend to a continuous map $ \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I have edited my post to include my detail as Rob Arthan suggested. 
   $\mathbb{R}^2_{std}$ refers to $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am kind of new, would it be acceptable to delete this post, and re-submit with all of these extra details, so maybe more people see it?

Comment: No, it's much better to edit the post (so long as it doesn't become a never-ending edit!). But you did right to ask.

Comment: @Rob I have edited it as you suggested. I didn't realize I could reply to you with the "@" character. Wait is this working? I can't tell....

Comment: Calum's example shows you that there are homeomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ that can't be carried to each other by a homeomorphism. In fact for $\mathbb R^3$ there are subsets homeomorphic to circles that can't be carried to each other by any homeomorphism. The simplest two examples are the trefoil knot and the unknot. They are both homeomorphic to $S^1$ but do not have homeomorphic complements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the question is corrected so that $g$ is a homeomorphism, what you are asking for is a proof of the [Schönflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem). That theorem is significantly stronger than the Jordan Curve Theorem itself. In fact, the only proofs I know of the Schönflies Theorem actually require knowing the Jordan Curve Theorem first, and from that point onwards the proof is still long and difficult.

You can read an outline of the proof of the Schönflies Theorem in the link provided, or you can look up the references given there.

In summary, if all you want is to prove the Jordan Curve Theorem, your outline is not what I would recommend.

Comment: A bummer, I thought I was close to a "new" proof of the Jordan Curve Theorem. Oh well. Thank you for the reference though.